# Hyper-V install error - Failure configuring windows features, reverting changes

Tags: windows-8, installation, hyper-v

I have a problem with the installation of Hyper-V in the Windows8.1. After selecting the component and reboot - is being installed, which is cut off by 93%. And "**Failure configuring windows features, reverting changes**".

Please, help me.

PS Sorry for my englsish.

Comment: Run [dism](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/26512-dism-fixing-component-store-corruption-windows-8-a.html) and `sfc /scannow` from an admin command prompt, then try installing Hyper-V again.

Comment: I ran into that problem before, but just tried installing again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The below fixed it for me.

Fixing Windows 2012R2 Hyper-V Role Failing at 99 Percent

https://interworks.com/blog/ijahanshahi/2013/12/06/fixing-windows-2012r2-hyper-v-role-failing-99-percent/

Resetting Windows Registry Files To Fix Hyper-V Role

sc config winmgmt start= disabled

net stop winmgmt /y

%systemdrive%

cd %windir%\system32\wbem

for /f %s in ('dir /b *.dll') do regsvr32 /s %s

regsvr32 %windir%\system32\tscfgwmi.dll

wmiprvse /regserver

net start winmgmt

for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s

cd C:\Windows\System32\wbem\AutoRecover

for /f %s in ('dir /b *.mof *.mfl') do mofcomp %s